# Vector inequality, how to prove it?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, vector-analysis

Foe a vector $v$ and $a,b$ such that

$  0 < 1-a-b \leq \| v\|^2  \leq 1-a+b $

with $ 0<a,b<1 $ it holds the inequality

$\parallel v - \dfrac{v}{\| v\|} \parallel \leq 1-\sqrt{1-a-b} $

How is this proven?

Comment: That doesn't look right to me.

Comment: Why the requirement $\lVert v \rVert ^2 \leq b$?

Comment: At the very least one would have to add $a > 0$, for otherwise $v = 0$ is allowed for.

Comment: I was trying to simplify an expression I found in a paper, I'll edit the question to make it more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The claim (as it was originally written -- the question has now morphed to something rather different) is perhaps not far from a correct one, but it's false as written.

Write $v = cu$ where $u$ has length $1$ (i.e., $u = v / \| v \|$) and $c = \|v\| \ge 0$. 
Then 
$$
\| v - \frac{v}{\|v\|}\| = \|cu - u\| = |c - 1|
$$

Now since 
$$
a \le \|v\|^2$$
we get 
$$
a \le c^2
$$
hence (if $a$ is positive, which was not specified), 
$$
\sqrt{a} \le c\\
\sqrt{a} - 1 \le c - 1.
$$

That's about as close to your claim as we can get, because the claim itself is false. For instance, in the reals, let $v = 1$. THen we have 
$$
-4 < |v|^2 < 12
$$
which should imply that 
$$
0 \le 1 - \sqrt{-4},
$$
which is nonsense.

Assuming that you forgot to include that $a \ge 0$, the claim is still wrong, as you can see from the case

$$
\frac{1}{4} \le \frac{1}{2}^2 \le 1.
$$
for in this case, the conclusion should be that 
$$
| \frac{1}{2} - 1 | < \frac{1}{4} - 1,
$$
which is false.

Comment: That you @JohnHuges, I edited my question to make it more precise. I hope it will help.

Comment: in the first equality you mean $|c-1|$ instead of $c-1$, right?

Comment: Yes. I'll edit. Thanks!.